# Using for loop to add tasks for creating a task scheduler that limits concurrency

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I followed the example at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx) to make my own demo for creating a task scheduler that limits concurrency. 
The maxDegreeOfParallelism is set to 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskSchedulerThatLimitsConcurrency
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a scheduler that uses two threads. 
            LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(2);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            // Create a TaskFactory and pass it our custom scheduler. 
            TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(lcts);
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

             // Use our factory to run a set of tasks. 
            Object lockObj = new Object();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var myFactory = new TaskFactory(lcts);
                Task t = myFactory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    lock (lockObj)
                    {
                        MakeTest(i, 1);
                    }
                }, cts.Token);
                tasks.Add(t);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var myFactory = new TaskFactory(lcts);
                Task t1 = myFactory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    lock (lockObj)
                    {
                        MakeTest(i, 2);
                    }
                }, cts.Token);
                tasks.Add(t1);
            }
            // Wait for the tasks to complete before displaying a completion message.
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSuccessful completion.");
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void MakeTest(int i, int p)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(i.ToString() + "_" + p.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The result is

[image: 1]

The task t1 and t2 is almost same. The difference is `MakeTest(i, 1)` and `MakeTest(i, 2)`. I wonder that can I use a second for loop to add the task?

I used the following code but obviously the result is wrong.

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var myFactory = new TaskFactory(lcts);
                Task t1 = myFactory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    lock (lockObj)
                    {
                        MakeTest(i, j+1);
                    }
                }, cts.Token);
                tasks.Add(t1);
            }
        }
```

The result:

[image: 2]

Questions:

1. Why my original code did not output the correct results such as "0_1", "1_1", etc.?
2. If with the second loop in my modified code, how to generate the correct results? Because in my real case the max DegreeOfParallelism is a big number. I can not add one by one to the task list as [MSDN example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx) I thought that I have to use a for loop.

Comment: "maxDegreeOfParallelism is a big number" what scenario would require you to "limit" the number of concurrent threads to a large number. I'm no expert but if this number is higher than the maximum number of threads the underlying hardware/vm can run concurrently then surely it won't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda that you are passing to `StartNew` creates a closure over the variables `i` and `j`. Because it's the *variable* that's closed-over and not the *value* of that variable, `MakeTest()` will be passed the value of `i` and `j` *at the time that MakeTest() is called, rather than their value at the time you call `StartNew`*. Supposing that your `for` loops complete before the first thread reaches that point in code, you'll always get the *last* value that `i` and `j` had as they passed through the `for` loop.

For more information, see Eric Lippert's article: http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

A simple fix would be to declare new variables inside of your `for` loops. Since these variables would be scoped within the loop, the captured value would remain what value that variable had during that particular iteration:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var capturedI = i;
        var capturedJ = j;
        ...
                    MakeTest(capturedI, capturedJ+1);
        ...
```

Comment: So how to fix it quickly?